# Test-Path incorrect file validation

Tags: powershell

This is an expected behavior:

```
PS C:\> Test-Path -Path C:\MyFolder\ -IsValid -PathType Container
True
PS C:\>
```

However, this seems to be incorrect:

```
PS C:\> Test-Path -Path C:\MyFolder\ -IsValid -PathType Leaf
True
PS C:\>
```

According to the official documentation:

> "Leaf. An element that does not contain other elements, such as a file."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-6

Is it a bug or did I miss something?

Note: The goal is to test the syntax of a file which does not yet exist. And the IsValid parameter is supposed to do that.

Comment: Wow ... you just crossposted this on at least three different forums/sites ... was it that urgent?

Comment: Just edited the question to be more clear about why I use the IsValid parameter.

Comment: `IsValid` check if a *Path* syntax is valid. It cares not for whether it is a file or folder, if it exists or not.

Comment: This is starting to look like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If you remove the `IsValid` and call a path that does not exist, you will get back false regardless of it it is a leaf or container.

Comment: To be clear I want to test the syntax of a path and not if the file exists. And this is exactly the purpose of the IsValid parameter. But it seems that the cmdlet is not able to make the distinction between a container and a leaf...

Comment: Yes it can make the distinction, but only for paths that exist

Comment: So far I understand, `IsValid` is not able to detect that **C:\MyFolder\** is always a folder and it cannot be a leaf object but only a container object.

Comment: There are two (2) results. The path is valid (True). The path is not a leaf (False). Which one do you want? Perhaps the parameters should be mutually exclusive, but they are not currently.

Comment: Yes exactly. If **IsValid** cannot make the difference between a container and a leaf, then **IsValid** and **PathType** should not belong to the same parameter set.

Comment: @Luke How would `Test-Path` distinguish between a *file* `C:\foo\bar.txt` and a *folder* `C:\foo\bar.txt`? The path is valid for both folders and files.

Comment: Yep! I agree with you on this example. But at least it should recognize **C:\Something\** for being a container/folder. It's the example of my original question.

Comment: `C:\Something` could be a file without extension as well ...  ;-)

Comment: Correct! I meant C:\Something\ but probably I mistakenly removed the last backslash while I was editing a few times the comment inorder to render the path bold.

Comment: By the way can someone explain me how to display a path as bold in a comment? I tried to surround it by 2 asterisks on each side and one asterisk on each side but none of it worked...

Comment: Let's wrap this up real quick: `Test-Path` isn't going to behave like you want it to anytime soon, so I suggest you fix the real problem instead. Don't define paths with trailing backslashes. Period. It's practically never required to have a trailing backslash in a path, and on the rare occasions you do need it you're better off appending it there and then anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft in [Github issue #8607](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8607):

> **-IsValid** and **-PathType** should have been in separate parameter sets

This has been referenced for a breaking change and the **-PathType** parameter has been appended with a Caution paragraph in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path#optional-parameters).

Answer (score 7):

`IsValid`is the overriding factor here

> IsValid: Indicates that this cmdlet tests the syntax of the path, regardless of whether the elements of the path exist.

As

```
PS C:\> Test-Path -Path C:\MyFolder\ -PathType Leaf
False
PS C:\>
```

Should behave as expected. (provided the path actually exists)

`IsValid` checks if a *Path* syntax is valid. It cares not for whether it is a file or folder, if it exists or not.

If you remove the `IsValid` and call a path that does not exist, you will get back *False* regardless of it is a leaf or container.